# Understand optional argument in R functions

Tags: r, function, optional-arguments

I don't quite understand optional argument return_sum=TRUE in the function() and what it does in this case.

It would be great if someone can explain under what circumstance would return_sum==TRUE.

```
linkedin <- c(16, 9, 13, 5, 2, 17, 14)
facebook <- c(17, 7, 5, 16, 8, 13, 14)
interpret <- function(num_views) {
  if (num_views > 15) {
    print("You're popular!")
    return(num_views)
  } else {
    print("Try to be more visible!")
    return(0)
  }
}
interpret_all <- function(views, return_sum=TRUE) {
  count <- 0

  for (v in views) {count<-count+interpret(v)

  }

  if (return_sum==TRUE) {return(count)

  } else {NULL

  }
}

interpret_all(linkedin)
interpret_all(facebook)
```

Answer (score 0):

`return_sum` is an argument to the function `interpret_all` whose default value is `TRUE` so if you don't pass any value to it it is considered as `TRUE`. The difference would be easy to see if you comment out the `print` statements

```
interpret <- function(num_views) {
   if (num_views > 15) {
     #print("You're popular!")
     return(num_views)
   } else {
     #print("Try to be more visible!")
     return(0)
    }
}

interpret_all <- function(views, return_sum=TRUE) {
    count <- 0
    for (v in views) count<- count + interpret(v)
    if (return_sum) return(count) else NULL
}
```

Now, check the difference

```
interpret_all(linkedin)
#[1] 33
interpret_all(linkedin, FALSE)
#NULL
interpret_all(linkedin, TRUE)
#[1] 33
```

---

Just an additional point based on your current logic you can reduce the function into one with minimising lines of code

```
interpret_all <- function(views, return_sum=TRUE) {
   if (return_sum) return(sum(views[views > 15])) else NULL
}
```

This would still give the same result

```
interpret_all(linkedin, TRUE)
#[1] 33
interpret_all(linkedin, FALSE)
#NULL
```

Comment: interpret_all also prints out all the comments(“you’re popular”, “try to be more visible”) according to the value.

Comment: @ChengQuincy yes, so you can keep the functions and print statements as it is. The point is `return_sum` is passed when calling the function `interpret_all` and if nothing is passed its default value is `TRUE`.